# Strange Safari CSS bug with CSS gradients

Tags: css, safari, gradient

[image: bug]

Hello,

I've added a CSS gradient to this button but there appears to be a weird line appearing. Is there some way I can fix this?

The CSS:

```
#view-content .billing-form #submit {
    background: #94c723; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #94c723 0%, #6cb119 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#94c723), color-stop(100%,#6cb119)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #94c723 0%,#6cb119 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #94c723 0%,#6cb119 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #94c723 0%,#6cb119 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #94c723 0%,#6cb119 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#94c723', endColorstr='#6cb119',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #a1d61a;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 70px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: I tried on Safari Version 5.1.2 (6534.52.7) with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8D9A/), and no problem. Could you provide the HTML code concerned as well?

Comment: The html is just an input type=submit. Also, I believe this affects the latest Safari (6?)

Comment: I'm updating my version of Safari. Meanwhile, check all the rules applied to your submit button with Safari's HTML/CSS inspector

Comment: Could you just use a width? It'd be a hack, but it may work... FYI, I'm not seeing the issue on fiddle either.

Comment: Could there be other CSS effecting the styling of the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought, but why not make the gradiant overlay on [pixlr](http://www.pixlr.com) and just set it as the background-image. Then you no longer have this problem and you save about ten lines of code..

Comment: This is the approach I went with in the end

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#view-content .billing-form #submit {
    background: #94c723; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #94c723 0%, #6cb119 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#94c723), color-stop(100%,#6cb119)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #94c723 0%,#6cb119 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #94c723 0%,#6cb119 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #94c723 0%,#6cb119 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #94c723 0%,#6cb119 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#94c723', endColorstr='#6cb119',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #a1d61a;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 70px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    display: block;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't fix the issue - thanks for your response though